# check out page from SharePoint 2013 designer workflow throws an error

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, variations

I have a somewhat complex requirement. We have implemented variations in our project. Now, when a page is created in the source site, we want to assign a unique id to this page. When this page is propagated to the target variation site, we don't want to change it's value and this would help us to create a relationship between the source page and all its target variations (SharePoint internally maintains some relationship  but we can't use it because it is not available via JSOM/REST and we can't use SSOM).

Now, we can use a workflow to get the GUID of the created page and assign it to my column (PageArticleID). But, there are 2 issues here.

1. We already have a publishing approval workflow (OOTB) defined on this library.
2. If i try to copy and modify the OOTB publishing approval workflow, I am facing another issue. I have to check out the page, assign the GUID to my column and check the page in. But, SharePoint throws an error : the operation failed because the action requires the document to be checked out.

I am not sure is this the expected behavior of SharePoint.

Is there a way we can handle this scenario?

Thanks in adcance.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [link](http://www.cleverworkarounds.com/2013/12/22/trials-or-tribulation-inside-sharepoint-2013-workflowspart-3/) for a possible solution.

Relevant part:
Uncheck the option for 'updating workflow status to list automatically'.
This is in designer, on the page having option 'Edit the workflow'

This is for point 2 of your question.